# Centering slides with react slick

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to put into effect a react-slick carousel but I'm having problem getting the image to vertically center. This problem is established right here.

https://codesandbox.Io/s/react-slick-playground-o7dhn

Images are not focused

Flexbox property does no longer work (the crimson div is a flexbox with justify-content: center;
align-gadgets: middle;)
margin:car simplest works for horizontal alignment (which I should not need to set if I'm using flexbox)
I can not remove the top margin (inspite of padding:0px at the div and margin-top:0px at the picture) As a outcome, any photo with the peak of 400px or extra gets shifted and reduce off (div has the height of 400px)

code in the sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "./index.css";

class ReactSlickDemo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: false,
      arrows: false
    };
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/400" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" />
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReactSlickDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: images are centered in your code sandbox

Comment: Always include code in your question with minimal reproducible example. Coding sandboxes are absolutely great for us to assist you and are VERY much appreciated but if you later edit that sandbox - or that site goes away people aren't able to see what the original problem was. I added it for you but be sure to include it in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem you can add this CSS into your component, I hope that's worked for you!

```
img {
    margin: auto;
}

.slick-slide > div {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```